# Harvest data from XML File

Tags: c#, xml

I need to write to an exception table.   So if the UploadStatus="Failed" I need to get the ClientLoanNumber and UploadedDt from the CDR_STATUS element and then whatever follows in the CDR_ERROR elements.   So I am thinking there is main loop for the CDR_STATUS and upon the condition UploadStatus="Failed" it loops through the CDR_STATUS element.  The return I would need is ClientLoanNumber, UploadedDt and the Message from the CDR_Status element.

The following is an actual response from a provider.  The formatting is crappy. Sorry.  I am c# developer, so looking for c#.  Thanks for your help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CWL_DATA>
  <CWL_RESPONSE  RequestType="CDRSearch" ClientID="11559" ResponseDateTime="6/26/2018 2:43:31 PM">
    <CRITERIA ReferenceNumber="412497" DateFrom="6/26/2018" DateTo="" UploadFileName="" />
    <RESPONSE_DATA>
      <CDR_STATUS UploadStatus="Failed" CWLLoanNumber="10050764" ClientLoanNumber="7000904180" FileName="WebService6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" UploadedDt="6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" BorrowerLastName="Beeching" LoanAmt="146520.00" LineType="Repo" RequestType="Wire" LoanStatus="Suspended" >
        <CDR_ERROR Message="Loan Number and / or Date Time stamp is not valid. Please download the excel file again and re-import using the new excel file."/>
        <CDR_ERROR Message="MFR Units is invalid."/>
        <CDR_ERROR Message="Please enter MIP% as a decimal number between 0.001 and 100 with up to 3 decimal digits."/>
      </CDR_STATUS>      <CDR_STATUS UploadStatus="Failed" CWLLoanNumber="10050766" ClientLoanNumber="7000907217" FileName="WebService6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" UploadedDt="6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" BorrowerLastName="Ginsburg" LoanAmt="69000.00" LineType="Repo" RequestType="Wire" LoanStatus="Suspended" >
        <CDR_ERROR Message="Loan Number and / or Date Time stamp is not valid. Please download the excel file again and re-import using the new excel file."/>
        <CDR_ERROR Message="MFR Units is invalid."/>
        <CDR_ERROR Message="Base Loan Amount is not required for  loans with Loan Type other than `FHA', 'CL FHA', 'VA' and 'CL VA'."/>
      </CDR_STATUS>      <CDR_STATUS UploadStatus="Failed" CWLLoanNumber="10050765" ClientLoanNumber="7000907225" FileName="WebService6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" UploadedDt="6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" BorrowerLastName="Cesaro" LoanAmt="83838.00" LineType="Repo" RequestType="Wire" LoanStatus="Suspended" >
        <CDR_ERROR Message="Loan Number and / or Date Time stamp is not valid. Please download the excel file again and re-import using the new excel file."/>
        <CDR_ERROR Message="MFR Units is invalid."/>
        <CDR_ERROR Message="Please enter MIP% as a decimal number between 0.001 and 100 with up to 3 decimal digits."/>
      </CDR_STATUS>      <CDR_STATUS UploadStatus="Pending" CWLLoanNumber="10050767" ClientLoanNumber="7000908314" FileName="WebService6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" UploadedDt="6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" BorrowerLastName="Massari" LoanAmt="191919.00" LineType="Repo" RequestType="Wire" LoanStatus="Suspended" >
      </CDR_STATUS>      <CDR_STATUS UploadStatus="Pending" CWLLoanNumber="10050768" ClientLoanNumber="7000909833" FileName="WebService6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" UploadedDt="6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" BorrowerLastName="Varney" LoanAmt="76312.00" LineType="Repo" RequestType="Wire" LoanStatus="Suspended" >
      </CDR_STATUS>      <CDR_STATUS UploadStatus="Pending" CWLLoanNumber="10050769" ClientLoanNumber="7000911722" FileName="WebService6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" UploadedDt="6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" BorrowerLastName="Lawson Cousins" LoanAmt="290000.00" LineType="Repo" RequestType="Wire" LoanStatus="Suspended" >
      </CDR_STATUS>      <CDR_STATUS UploadStatus="Pending" CWLLoanNumber="10050770" ClientLoanNumber="7000911763" FileName="WebService6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" UploadedDt="6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" BorrowerLastName="Ball" LoanAmt="207570.00" LineType="Repo" RequestType="Wire" LoanStatus="Suspended" >
      </CDR_STATUS>      <CDR_STATUS UploadStatus="Pending" CWLLoanNumber="10050771" ClientLoanNumber="7000914155" FileName="WebService6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" UploadedDt="6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" BorrowerLastName="Rauf" LoanAmt="404700.00" LineType="Repo" RequestType="Wire" LoanStatus="Suspended" >
      </CDR_STATUS>      <CDR_STATUS UploadStatus="Pending" CWLLoanNumber="10050773" ClientLoanNumber="7000915947" FileName="WebService6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" UploadedDt="6/26/2018 2:43:25 PM" BorrowerLastName="Dino" LoanAmt="245471.00" LineType="Repo" RequestType="Wire" LoanStatus="Suspended" >
      </CDR_STATUS>    </RESPONSE_DATA>

  </CWL_RESPONSE>
</CWL_DATA>
```

Comment: If you make an attempt at writing the code and have a specific problem then we can help you, but we're not here to write your code from scratch - please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Agree with @JohnM. Some code trials please

Comment: So are you dumping actual customer data on a public website...?

Comment: No, I only used test data

Answer (score 1):

This is what I worked out.

```
            DataTable resultsDT = new DataTable();
            resultsDT.Columns.Add("LoanNUmber");
            resultsDT.Columns.Add("Error");

            XDocument X = XDocument.Load(pathStatusRequestResult);

            var status = X.Element("CWL_DATA").Element("CWL_RESPONSE");
            var statusData = status.Element("RESPONSE_DATA").Elements("CDR_STATUS");

            foreach(var item in statusData)
            {
                // returns the value of teh UploadStatus
                bool uploadStatus = (item.Attribute("UploadStatus").Value) == "Failed" ? false : true;
                string loanNumber = item.Attribute("ClientLoanNumber").Value;

                if (uploadStatus == false)
                {
                    var errorData = item.Elements("CDR_ERROR");

                    foreach(var e in errorData)
                    {
                        string error = e.Attribute("Message").Value;
                        resultsDT.Rows.Add(loanNumber, error);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: If you have solved the problem, you could accept your own answer to show others it is solved. :)

Comment: Looks like you took some of my code, but you are not getting the date you requested.

Comment: Actually not.  I did find some sample code that I I did leverage.  Then I put elements into strings until I figured out how to get the items I needed.  The tricky part was the 2nd loop.

Answer (score -1):

I put results into a datatable :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ClientLoanNumber", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("UploadedDt", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Error", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> failed = doc.Descendants("CDR_STATUS").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("UploadStatus") == "Failed").ToList();

            foreach (var fail in failed)
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                newRow["ClientLoanNumber"] = (string)fail.Attribute("CWLLoanNumber");
                newRow["UploadedDt"] = DateTime.ParseExact((string)fail.Attribute("UploadedDt"), "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                newRow["Error"] = string.Join("\n", fail.Elements("CDR_ERROR").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("Message")));
            }

        }
    }
}
```